# Lion Photobooth Pictures

Tags: macos, photo-booth

In previous versions of OSX I've been able to take a picture using the Photobooth app and upload it to the internet (by using a website's "choose file" button, navigating to User\Pictures\Photobooth or similar and selecting the picture I want).

Now, since I've upgraded to lion I haven't been able to do this.

Now the Photobooth folder in my Pictures directory is disabled and I cannot get into it.

So how can I use Photos from Photobooth in every day life? (ie: not just in photobooth?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in the Open File dialog box, there is a heading in the sidebar that says "Media". Under that heading is an entry for Photos. Click that, and then at the top of the dialog, it will show any iPhoto albums you have. But, if you scroll down to the bottom, you can select "Photo Booth", and you should be able to load all your photo booth pictures from there. Unless I'm missing something, that should be all you need.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can still access them.

1. Rick-Click on Photo Booth Library in `~/Pictures`
2. Select **Show Package Contents**.
3. The Pictures are located in `~/Pictures/Photo Booth Library/Pictures`

Still, you'll not be able to access the photos via the "choose file" dialog. So you might have to copy the folder once in a while. Also, creating an alias for the folder does not work in finder. Maybe someone can come up with the Terminal command?

Comment: You can access the folder in the Choose File dialog by pressing cmd-shift-g and typing `~/Pictures/Photo Booth Library/Pictures`. You can make a symlink from Terminal with `ln -s ~/Pictures/Photo\ Booth\ Library/Pictures/ /where/you/want/alias`

Comment: @NathanGreenstein That's nice! I did not know that cmd-shift-g works here aswell. The symlink command is something I'll take a note off in my head. I tried to figure this out myself, but all info I found was related to creating alias for terminal commands like ``alias l='ls -lsai'``

Comment: hi guys, thanks for the help, but thekmc has actually given the right answer. It works if you go to "Media" and click "Photos" under that.